# Get-SPList cmdlet Fails but still can browse to list

Tags: powershell

I am looking for reasons why the PowerShell cmdlet Get-SPList fails for a URL that can be browsed to.  The URL is a valid list. Here is the cmdlet and error.  I can use browser to get to the list.  **I am in a SharePoint 2010 environment.**

```
Get-SPList http://listurl...

Get-SPList : The SPList Pipebind object could not be found (Id or Url : http://listurl...).
At line:1 char:11
+ Get-SPList <<<<  http://listurl...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Lapointe.ShareP...SPCmdletGetList:SPCmdletGetList) [Get-SPList], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Lapointe.SharePoint.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Lists.SPCmdletGetList
```

Comment: I see that's an error related to [PowerShell-SPCmdlets](https://github.com/glapointe/PowerShell-SPCmdlets). Do you have all the assemblies referenced correctly? Post more code to try to guess the reason

Comment: yes all of that is in place. The cmdlet fails for the specific URL of a specific web application.

Comment: One other observation. I can call Get-SPWeb then get the targeted SPList from the Lists property.  It seems related to the Get-SPList cmdlet and the list I am trying to return.

Comment: Do you have any custom event receivers on that list? Anything special about the list?